# How to in Jenkins exclude certain folder from build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I use Jenkins to deploy builds from git to server. But, I have 2 folder with same names in different places in build folder tree. How to exclude from build one of folder. Example:

```
..
/app
/backups
/resources
         |
         +--/views
                |
                +--/vendor (include)
/vendor (exclude)
```

Comment: This depends on how you told Jenkins to deploy.

Comment: Add more details. How you are deploying? Copying over SSH/SFTP? Are these inside a zip? How build is generated? Is it built for all independently and then assembled together?

Comment: I have deploying by SFTP, it's a Laravel project (The PHP Framework). When I set up ```**/vendor/**``` as exclude at build settings Jenkins undeploy any folders with names "vendor"